# Universal Image Loader: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to *server*

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I need to handle the error when the server is down.

I'm using UIL to populate a recycler view that contains a list of items with a logo image. Each image logo of each list item is stored in a server. When the server is up, everythng it's ok. The problem comes when the server is down, UIL give this error:

```
E/ImageLoader: failed to connect to the.custom.server/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (port 80) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
                                                                java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to the.custom.server/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (port 80) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
```

It's ok, I know the server is down. I need is to handle this. Where can I catch this error to act according?

Here is my UIL configuration:

```
private void setup() {
    if(UniversalImageLoader.imageLoader!=null &&
            UniversalImageLoader.imageLoader.isInited()){
        UniversalImageLoader.imageLoader.destroy();
    }

    // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
            .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(UniversalImageLoader.context)
            .threadPoolSize(5)
            .threadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY + 2)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new ImageFileNameGenerator())
            .build();

    UniversalImageLoader.imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    UniversalImageLoader.imageLoader.init(config);

}
```

Here it's the portion code to load the image in the recycler view adapter:

```
    ...

    holder.ivImage.setImageBitmap(null);

    if (_mCommerces.get(position).getUrlImageIcon() != null &&
            !_mCommerces.get(position).getUrlImageIcon().equals("")) {

        final File image = DiskCacheUtils
                .findInCache(_mCommerces.get(position).getUrlImageIcon(),
                        UniversalImageLoader.imageLoader.getDiskCache());

        if (image != null && image.exists()) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(image).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.ivImage);
        } else {
            UniversalImageLoader.imageLoader
                    .loadImage(_mCommerces.get(position).getUrlImageIcon(),
                            new ImageLoadingListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {
                                    holder.ivImage.setImageBitmap(null);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, final Bitmap bitmap) {
                                    Picasso.with(context).load(s).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.ivImage);

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {

                                }
                            });
        }
    } else {
        holder.ivImage.setImageBitmap(null);
    }

    ...
```

Thak you so much for your time.

Comment: Take a look at failReason inside the onLoadingFailed

Comment: I tried that. The error occurs before to reach that method I think. TY!